# Passing XMLHttpRequest to PHP results in empty $POST

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, post, xmlhttprequest

So far, I have been working on some code, and have been troubleshooting for awhile and I'm pretty sure my syntax is correct. I've been having to work around a broken testing environment so I can't use normal breakpoints to test this on the backend.

I have the following function in javascript:

```
function ns_submit_form_inpage(path, data){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            alert("Message Sent");
        }
    }
    request.open('POST', path, true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    var temp_string = array_to_string(data);
    alert("data:"+ temp_string);
    request.send(data);
}
```

And the following code in PHP:

```
<?php
    mail("my_email@example.com", "Array: ". print_r($_POST, true), "From:test@example.com");
?>
```

I call the function, pass my path in along with an array. I get an email and a proper alert, so I know my function is called and the right file is hit and fires. A also know that right before I send off the data, they data is properly in the keyed array (e.g. first_name::bob, last_name::doe). However, the email I receive reads "Array: Array()" and confirmation via my "Message Sent" alert.

I've narrowed down where I think my error could be, and I'm done to pretty much nothing left, it feels like the array is just disappearing into the ether of the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue. As mentioned, I was sending the data as an array. Although PHP *reads* the accepted data as an array, and I'm *sending* an array, the method by which the array is sent (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) doesn't USE an array. It uses a *string.* So, I had to change the array into a string following the format of "first_name=bob&last_name=doe&foo=bar". Now it works.